# Dual initialization of same name global variable in different classes

Tags: java, android, c++, matlab, java-native-interface

I have googled myself dead with this, but I haven't quite found the answer I was after!

I used JNI to implement some MATLAB generated code. Because I need to run it twice at the same time, I have implemented this class based and then initialized two instances of this class.

They do, however, contain a lot of global variable initialization, so when I was using it that way, the output of both instances was just plain wrong and I couldn't explain myself why (I checked with the matlab implementation).

I then implemented the same solution as separate libraries, which worked without errors.

I'm now wondering why the other implementation didn't work.
In C++, omitting static doesn't automatically imply an external definition, does it?

Would both class instances refer to the same variables, even though they should have been initialized within the separate instances?

I'm sorry if this is a brainfart and I'm asking something obvious, I'm in the last week of my bachelor thesis and my brain is fried!

Thanks!

Edit: of course, code:

It basically looked like this:

```
ClassName* ClassName::p_ClassName //Definition in Header

ClassName::ClassName(){


{

ClassName::~ClassName
{
   p_ClassName = NULL;

}


GlobalVariable variableName;


ClassName::funktion(){

variableName = value;

}
```

Comment: Posting some code would help to clarify your question - how you declare you variables, how you initialise and use them.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Edited

Comment: _"Would both class instances refer to the same variables, even though they should have been initialized within the separate instances?"_ Having a global variable implies that it's **not** separate per class instance, but shared within your library. If you want to have per-object variables, then make them non-static members of the class.

Comment: Great thanks! That is what I expected and I needed confirmed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, omitting `static` does mean a function or variable is global (but not necessarily exported across libraries).

See e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/

Comment: Ok, I could only find that to be true for C, didn't find anything about that being true for C++ as well, but if that's the case I'm affirmed in my suspicion!